# Blender Coordinates to three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, blender

I have loaded the model that I have exported through blender in three.js. I'm using the following code to position the axis,

```
var axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper( 10 );

axesHelper.position.x =0.21785;
axesHelper.position.y =  2.85146;
axesHelper.position.z = 0.800149;
```

I obtained these coordinates from the blender. Unfortunately, these coordinates are in wrong position when I view it from three.js. what am I missing?

Comment: Three.js uses +Y as the up axis. Blender uses +Z as up. You'll have to do the position conversion yourself.

Comment: @Marquizzo would it work if I just swap the y and z axis? Or does it also depends on the rotation?

Comment: Try it and see what you get.

Comment: Which export format are you using ? Did you `apply modifiers` on geometries at export step ?